# Getting a ClassNotFound exception when using mongotemplate

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am getting the following exception when running a spring boot application that uses the mongo template:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDatabaseFactory
```

This is the main code:

```java
package com.example.redismongo.mongodb;

import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.config.EnableMongoAuditing;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;

@Configuration
@EnableMongoAuditing
public class MongoConfiguration {


    @Bean
    public MongoClient mongo(){
        return MongoClients.create("mongodb://localhost:27017");
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "mongoTemplate")
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate(){
        return new MongoTemplate(mongo(), "test");
    }
}
```

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-commons', version: '2.2.8.RELEASE'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-mongodb', version: '2.2.8.RELEASE'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I need to test the 2.2.8 version as that is the version that is being used at work. I am trying to test some of its functionality in my pc to test certain fail scenarios. How can I make 2.2.8 work?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb` instead of `spring-data-mongodb`.